Please explain this interaction in Patriot Games
I've seen Patriot Games (1992) many times, but I've never understood this interaction. Here is the dialogue, about an hour into the film:

Cantor: You are the victim of a crime. And that does not make for the best analysis even if you knew something about terrorism, which you do not. I have guys on it, guys who know something about the IRA.
Ryan: Marty, I am not standing here with my hat in my hand! I am telling you, I want back in.
Greer: Jack?
Ryan: Sir.
Greer: Thank God about Sally.
Ryan: Thank you.
Greer: Alice and I are relieved beyond words. You manage any sleep?
Ryan: Not much, sir.
Greer: I'm interrupting something. You were explaining to Jack about how we'd be better off without him around here, or something along those lines.

Following this exchange, Ryan looks validated, and in the next scene he's working at the CIA again. Didn't Greer just say Ryan wasn't needed? What is the nuance I'm missing?

clip available here: https://youtu.be/Bvur8UIHtAs?si=xiAhLi7mwyZ44A_g at 0:36

Greer has a close relationship with Ryan and trusts him.  Now that he is in the room and obviously close to Ryan personally its now much harder for Cantor to dismiss his wishes.
The dialog you have here doesn't show Greer rejecting Ryan's help as you suggest; it shows Cantor attempting to reject Ryan's help, and Greer overriding him.
The last line:

You were explaining to Jack about how we'd be better off without him around here, or something along those lines.

is Greer talking to Cantor, referencing what he just said about not needing Ryan.  This is done as a joke, in a way that he believes that  (a) Ryan will be more useful than Cantor expects and (b) Greer is overruling Cantor.
The intervening lines including "Alice and I are relieved" (Alice is presumably Greer's wife) demonstrates the close personal friendship that exists between Ryan and Greer. Greer is Deputy Director of the CIA and presumably outranks Cantor.
Having watched the video clip, I think it's played fairly subtly but you can see that Jack smiles when he goes back to looking at Cantor.

How much of the meaning of that last line of dialogue is in the words, and how much is in the delivery?  As written, it looks like a straight agreement with Cantor — was it said in a way to rule out that possibility (such as with irony, or a questioning tone)?

@gidds The most significant nuance, I think, is that Greer is stating a conclusion he already reached about their conversation, rather than asking Cantor what it was about. He's made up his mind and intruded without really caring what Cantor has to say about it - he wouldn't have bothered if he was just going to tell Cantor to carry on as before.

@gidds the delivery is fairly straight too, but that kind of line where a character asks another to resume something that is now obviously a little silly, is a bit of a trope.  Now that Greer is in the room, its going to be a bit harder to be so dismissive of Jack.

"you can see that Jack smiles when he goes back to looking at Cantor." - yes, it's this smile I don't understand. I get what you're saying, but I don't understand how Greer's comment is automatically interpreted as tacit approval for Ryan to return. I am wondering how this nuance works: what is it about Greer's "we'd be better off without him around here, or something along those lines" gives this approval when it appears negative to me?

@Grosvenor ...  but he's not necessarily saying he agrees with Cantor's assessment - he's merely saying that he interrupted him and is inviting Cantor, now in his presence, to repeat it.  Jack now has an ally in the conversation

There's a lot of weight in the word "were"... Cantor was having that conversation with Jack. Greer never said it (on screen), but there was a strong implication that said conversation was over because Greer wanted Jack back in. The "or something along those lines" bit is also him dismissing Cantor's position by saying the precise details of whatever he was saying are irrelevant.

I think the intervening exchange about Jack's wife is key to the scene: Greer is not-so-subtly making a point to Cantor: that he and Jack and have a very close relationship, and therefore that Cantor needs to reconsider his dismissal of Jack's offer of help. His final line is handing the ball back to Cantor, but the implication of what result is needed is clear.

The heart of the meaning is in Jack's response, "I am not standing here with my hat in my hand!"
That is a Western culture idiom. Person 1 who goes to beg for something from Person 2 might take his hat off to address Person 2, as a sign of respect and submission.
With that statement Jack is telling Marty Cantor that he (Jack) is not worthless to the cause, that he is not asking for a favor. He's telling Cantor that he can provide great value to the cause.

I'd always assumed "hat in hand" derives from the act of begging for money, loose coins or otherwise. One holds out one's hat as an easy target for someone to toss a coin into while passing by.

"That statement" being the last sentence the OP references, I presume, or your answer doesn't make a lot of sense.

@uhoh, Dictionary.com supports the understanding I always had of that idiom, that it is about removing one's hat as a gesture of respect, especially to someone who is in a position of authority over you. In modern English, the idiom is certainly about asking for a favor, though, so maybe there has been a mixture of influences.

@JohnBollinger OK I see. It's from a routine-hat-wearing era.
